# Xamarin IOS - class does not have a default parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I keep getting the below error in my Xamarin IOS app. My app builds fine but Apple keep rejecting it, so I think it is down to this error. The error is:
"The Y4P.Views.PlayVideo class does not have a default parameterless constructor. This xaml file cannot be previewed unless a parameterless constructor is added. This constructor should invoke the standard 'Initialize component' method if the class has one.

XAML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:InTheHand.Forms;assembly=InTheHand.Forms"
              x:Class="Y4P.Views.PlayVideo"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,20">
     <forms:MediaElement HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="650" x:Name="Media" IsLooping="False"  AreTransportControlsEnabled="true" Source="{Binding URL}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>



    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using AVFoundation;
    using AVKit;
    using Foundation;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Y4P.Models;
    using Y4P.ViewModels;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace Y4P.Views
    {
        public partial class PlayVideo : ContentPage
        {
            ItemDetailViewModel viewModel;

            public PlayVideo(ItemDetailViewModel viewModel)
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Y4P.Views.PlayVideo class does not have a default parameterless
>   constructor. This xaml file cannot be previewed unless a parameterless
>   constructor is added. This constructor should invoke the standard
>   'Initialize component' method if the class has one.

Is true, according to the code you shared. So if you want to get rid of this error add a parameterless constructor, so it will be possible to preview the XAML:

```
public PlayVideo()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

> my app builds fine but apple keep rejecting it

Regarding the statement above, it unlikely to be related to parameterless constructor. Usually Apple provides a feedback with a single or multiple points that have been potentially violated. I would recommend to recheck their response and to act accordingly.